# Why doesn't my stylesheet that is simply linked from the HTML file, apply?

Tags: css

[image]

I found an error at my google chrome Developer Tools > Console… "Not allowed to load local resource".  It could be the reason why the stylesheet from "style.css" doesn't apply to the HTML page ("index.html") where it is linked from., despite using an absolute pathing.

Both files are in the same directory. I also tried clearing the browsing data (cache) but it didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know a solution?

The "index.html" file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Table of Contents</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body >
  <h1>Introduction</h1>
  <h2>Whom this book is for?</h2>
  <h2>Errata</h2>
  <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
  <h2>What you will learn in this chapter</h2>
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
  <h2>Recap</h2>
  <h2>Conclusion</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The "style.css" file:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    color: white; background-color: navy;
}
h2 {
    color: green; margin-left: 40px; border-bottom: 4px dotted black;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll avoid to ask you if the file is effectively called "style.css", so I ask if you have tried to perform `Ctrl+F5` command. This is supposed to reload not only the HTML web page, but also the external stylesheets.

Comment: it is applying ,did you save after edit style page

Comment: Yes, I've already tried reloading the page, even re-opening a new chrome browser with cleared browser data cache history.  Also, there is no shown error in the coder terminal.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/> please remove media and try again

Comment: Could you try opening the HTML file in an incognito window of Chrome and then go to the **Network tab** of **Developer Tools** (via Right Click -> **Inspect** and then selecting Network tab) and then refresh the page. What does the Network tab show for style.css line?

Comment: Hi Kaushalya.  I tried your instruction, and I think my attempt might not be precise.  Nonetheless, please see the uploaded pic above. Maybe you can give me more insight

Comment: localhost/:5 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C://Users//ASUS/Desktop//My_Samples//Chapter01//Ex1-5_CSS//style.css

Comment: Found this error on my chrome browser DevelopTool > Console.  I have tried using absolute path, however it says "Not allowed to load local resource:"

Comment: Jeffrey, Can you try opening the HTML file directly with **Ctrl + O**? (rather than from localhost:5000)
Does it load correctly or this also give the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in command prompt

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and after that perform `Ctrl+F5` command

I think this will work.

Comment: This works just for Windows OS, so here there are the commands to perform on Linux and Mac OS.

**Linux:** `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart`

**Mac OS Sierra, X El Capitan, X Mavericks, X Mountain Lion, or X Lion:** `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

**Mac OS X Yosemite:** `sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches`

**Mac OS X Snow Leopard:** `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

**Mac OS X Leopard:** `sudo lookupd -flushcache`

Comment: Still didn't work after Ctrl+F5 command at the web page, although the terminal showed 'successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache

Answer (score -1):

You can add `ver=1.0` or `ver=1.1` at the last of `.css` extionsins like `href="style.css"?ver=1.0, then reload the page`Ctrl+F5Ctrl+shift+F5` command.

I think this will you support.

Comment: Tried both versions, but still the same styleless page after reload

Comment: Do you verify with the Cross Browsing platform or 'browser's Incognito window'? are you using a window or MAC?

Comment: I verified with incognito, same.  I'm using window

Answer (score -1):

1. make sure style .css file save as .css file.
2. else remove media form your link tag.
3. Try Ctrl+u in chrome and click on the link href if you are able to find css,it should work else change the path.
4. Move files somewhere on a network drive(from C drive).